# Mozilla not getting SAML context

Tags: spring-saml

I am using  below code to get my credential, it is woking fine in IE,
Why it is not working in mozilla.

```
SecurityContextImpl obj = (SecurityContextImpl) session
            .getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT");
SAMLCredential credential = (SAMLCredential) obj.getAuthentication()
            .getCredentials();
```

if any body has encounter situation like this.
I am using Spring SAML

Comment: Resolved as responseSkew was I am using the default 60  below change helped      <pre><code><bean id="webSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl">
    <property name="responseSkew" value="600"/> <!-- 10 minutes -->
</bean></code>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved as responseSkew was I am using the default 60 below change helped

```
<bean id="webSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl"> <property name="responseSkew" value="600"/> <!-- 10 minutes --> </bean>
```